# Overide Backbone sync globally with Browserify

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var servicesNew = {
    readUrl :"",
    deleteUrl :"",
    updateUrl :"",
    createUrl :"",

    primaBackbone : function(method, model, options) {
        options || (options = {});

        var beforeSend = options.beforeSend;
        options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {

          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer 52b20db1-4bcb-426e-9bbf-a53a826249f3')
          if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
        };
        // passing options.url will override 
        // the default construction of the url in Backbone.sync

        switch (method) {
            case "read":
                options.url = readUrl;
                break;
            case "delete":
                options.url = deleteUrl+'/'+model.get("id");
                break;
            case "update":
                options.url = updateUrl+'/'+model.get("id");
                break;
             case "create":
                options.type = "PUT";
                options.url = createUrl;
                break;    
        }

        if (options.url)
            return Backbone.sync.call(model, method, model, options);
    }    
}

module.exports = servicesNew;
```

**My Model:**

```
    // Filename: models/project
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
    Urls= require('../../libs/urls'),
    servicesNew = require('../../libs/servicesnew');

var NotificationHeaderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

      sync: function(){

        servicesNew.readUrl = Urls.notifications.unread;
        servicesNew.createUrl = Urls.notifications.list;
        servicesNew.deleteUrl = Urls.notifications.list;
        servicesNew.updateUrl = Urls.notifications.list;



        return Backbone.sync = servicesNew.primaBackbone();

      }


});
// Return the model for the module
module.exports = NotificationHeaderModel;
```

**IN View:**

```
    this.model.fetch({
   success: function(model, response, options){

    console.log(response);
     _this.template = notificationTemplate;

     _this.$el.html(_this.template({notificationData: response,notificationType:notifyMsg.notificationType()
      ,notificationMessage:notifyMsg.notificationMessage()}));
   },
   error: function(model, xhr, options){


    alert(xhr.result.Errors);
  }
});
```

**I am trying to override the Backbone.sync method Backbone globally however i am unable to do so.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would ditch attributes on the `servicesNew` object and use the `options` object to pass the urls
2. your models' sync methods won't work like that, you're reassigning `Backbone.sync` and you don't pass any argument.

A potential solution could be

```
var servicesNew = {
    primaBackbone : function(method, model, options) {
        options || (options = {});

        var beforeSend = options.beforeSend;
        options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer 52b20db1-4bcb-426e-9bbf-a53a826249f3')
            if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        switch (method) {
            case "read":
                options.url = options.readUrl;
                break;
            case "delete":
                options.url = options.deleteUrl+'/'+model.get("id");
                break;
            case "update":
                options.url = options.updateUrl+'/'+model.get("id");
                break;
             case "create":
                options.type = "PUT";
                options.url = options.createUrl;
                break;    
        }

        if (options.url)
            return Backbone.sync.call(model, method, model, options);
    }
}
```

And the model definition

```
var NotificationHeaderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

      sync: function(method, model, options){
          options = _.defaults({}, options, {
              readUrl: Urls.notifications.unread,
              createUrl: Urls.notifications.list,
              deleteUrl: Urls.notifications.list,
              updateUrl: Urls.notifications.list
          });

          return servicesNew.primaBackbone.call(model, method, model, options);
      }

});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/mn0eo6eb/

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "globally" the above code only replaces the sync method for that particular Backbone Model (NotificationHeaderModel). If you want to replace the actual sync behind everything, it should be Backbone.sync (http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

```
    servicesNew.readUrl = Urls.notifications.unread;
    servicesNew.createUrl = Urls.notifications.list;
    servicesNew.deleteUrl = Urls.notifications.list;
    servicesNew.updateUrl = Urls.notifications.list;

    Backbone.sync = servicesNew.primaBackbone.bind(servicesNew);
```

Update: another thing is that you should assign the method `primaBackbone` to `Backbone.sync` instead of the returned value. Also, it is important that you should handle both case model and collection in your custom sync (if you don't need collections, then it is ok)

Update: Because you are using incorrect variables in the method. Calling readUrl alone refers to the `global` scope which is obviously undefined

Full code

```
var servicesNew = {
  readUrl :"",
  deleteUrl :"",
  updateUrl :"",
  createUrl :"",

  primaBackbone : function(method, model, options) {
    options || (options = {});

    var beforeSend = options.beforeSend;
    options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {

      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer 52b20db1-4bcb-426e-9bbf-a53a826249f3')
      if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    // passing options.url will override 
    // the default construction of the url in Backbone.sync

    switch (method) {
        case "read":
            options.url = this.readUrl;
            break;
        case "delete":
            options.url = this.deleteUrl+'/'+model.get("id");
            break;
        case "update":
            options.url = this.updateUrl+'/'+model.get("id");
            break;
         case "create":
            options.type = "PUT";
            options.url = this.createUrl;
            break;    
    }

    return Backbone.sync.call(model, method, model, options);
  }    
}

 module.exports = servicesNew;
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined i get this error

Comment: Hey i still get the same error edited my code as above

Comment: The options.url etc are not getting set its not going inside  if (options.url)
            return Backbone.sync.call(model, method, model, options);

Comment: How about just returning `return Backbone.sync.call(model, method, model, options);` (without the if) since Backbone has already checked it for you. Another thing is, you need to store the original Backbone.sync somewhere else before re-using it in your `primaBackbone` method

Comment: Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified if i remove the if statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77782/discussion-between-vini-and-tan-nguyen).